# How to handle questions which are resolved by circumstances which are not part of the question

Tags: discussion

On stackoverfow we have a Off Topic close reason

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced
>   or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be
>   on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help
>   future readers. ...

How useful are questions like [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/152508/27928) for future readers, should they be closed/flagged, if yes with which reason, or should they be kept.

Comment: I think that question might be somewhat useful because at least it's an example of working code. The useless ones are where the question doesn't include code / schematics etc and the answer is something like "the batteries were flat", but they can just be closed as "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: It's a common problem for questions on [tag:system-verilog], [tag:vhdl] etc. I think the close reason on StackOverflow is required for EE.SE as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a point, and such questions could be closed as <s>"too localized"</s>, as they are unlikely to help anyone else than the OP. (EDIT: "too localized" is not available anymore, and no other option seems to fit the case).

In the specific case of the linked question, I'm not sure it can't help anyone else with similar problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my questions was asking for general advice, the question was the best example I could find on electronics. "Too localized" is not part of the flagging options, I know it from older SO dialogs, "to broad" might be the closest reason, would it be appropriate for questions as described in the title?

Comment: @bummi you're right, I think none of the current closing options applies. I don't know how often this is needed, but may be added to the list.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I did not find many here until now, on SU I'm missing it terrible since many questions are of this type. I'll report here if I find more.